# FFmpeg compile error

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, makefile, libavcodec

I get an error when compiling my project *ffmpeg*. I followed this guide : [TheGuide](http://ywanguu.blogspot.fr/2013/02/how-to-prepare-your-mac-for-ios.html).

When I execute the command `make` I get this error message:

```
AS  libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.o
libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.S:88:9: error: unknown directive
        .hword (60f - 0b) / 2, (61f - 0b) / 2, (62f - 0b) / 2, (63f - 0b) / 2, (64f - 0b) / 2
...
make: *** [libavcodec/arm/mlpdsp_armv5te.o] Error 1
```

I do develop on a `MAC` with `OS X mavericks`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for Mac OS, you probably don't need to build something for ARM v5. Same thing goes for iOS (I believe the baseline is ARM v5, but correct me if I'm wrong).

Build it for x86_64 or x86_32 and it should work.